# Peel and stick vinyl planks over vinyl

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I have an existing vinyl floor and I bought some peel and stick vinyl planks to lay over it.

My existing floor has "texture" to it. By that, I mean that it has shape. Its basically imitating tiles, and therefore, where the grout should be, it is slightly lower, something like a millimetter or less. Does that justify applying some sort of leveler, or can I just apply the primer to the floor and put the tiles down?

Here is a picture:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not a fan of putting down vinyl over vinyl.  Instead of leveling, I would strongly encourage you to remove the old floor, clean the underlying surface, possibly lay down a new sublayer of hardboard (basically pressed cardboard) and then apply your tile to that.

Vinyl over vinyl as stated by Damon will result in poor adhesion and if you're going to the trouble of leveling it, you may as well remove it and clean it up.  Building up the floor again and again will also result in uneven step differences between rooms.

Comment: The texture of the original vinyl floor can also telegraph into the new layer if it is not removed. You may not see it right away, but over time, you will begin to see the pattern of the underlying floor.

Answer (score 0):

The uneven surface will only do harm and no good for adhesion of the new tiles.  How much is not possible to say for certain.

I would definitely recommend leveling the texture as much as possible.  As for leveling you would need a product designed to adhere to vinyl; not cementitious self leveling compound.  I think a latex based leveling compound should work.

After things are level'd better you should be good to go with the new tiles.